# Локальное вращение

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я хочу заствить куб поворачиватся на 90 градусов каждый раз когда я нажимаю на одну из половин экрана. 
(С нажатием и определением сторон экрана проблем нет)
Куб должен повернутся строго на 90 градусов и после каждого его поворота его позицию нужно признать (0,0,0) но я не могу понять как это реальзовать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На премере этого скриншота, я поверну куб на 90 градусов по оси z и у меня фиолетовый цвет будет на верху. 
После чего я поверну куб по оси X и у меня должен зеленый цвет встать на место фиолетогого. Но выходит иначе, я вижу такую картину что оси смещаются во время поворота.

```
           if (touch.position.x > Camera.main.scaledPixelWidth/2)
            {
             Box.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(90, 0, 0), 90f);
            }
            if (touch.position.x < Camera.main.scaledPixelWidth/2)
            {
             Box.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, -90), 90f);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вращение происходит вокруг начала координат, то после поворота на 90 градусов вокруг любой базовой оси куб сместится в другой октант пространства.

Чтобы он оставался в том же положении (но с другой ориентацией), матрицу преобразования нужно модифицировать - смещение на `-Size/2` по всем координатам, вращение, обратное смещение.

**Edit:**

Посмотрел - в unity [есть функция](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html)

```
 RotateAround(Vector3 point, Vector3 axis, float angle);
```

point в данном случае середина куба, axis соответственно оси вращения  - например, (1,0,0) для вращения вокруг оси, параллельной OX.

Comment: Не очень вас понял , можно с примерами кода ?

Comment: У меня нет кода. Вы знаете, что такое аффинные преобразования?

Comment: Нет, если есть ссылка с хорошей статьей буду благодарен. Я пока ещё студент )

Comment: Думаю, `Transform.RotateAround` будет достаточно - добавил в ответ

Comment: Спас мою жизнь )